# How to set a minimum date range limit for the Date Range Picker

Tags: javascript, daterangepicker

I am using the Date Range Picker from daterangepicker.com.
How can I set a minimum date range limit for this Date Range Picker?
For example, I want to set minimum limit of 3 days so the user can only select a date range of 3 days or more.

At the moment my code for the date range picker is just simply instantiating it with:

```
$('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker();
```

Comment: standard date inputs accept a `min` attrib

Comment: @dandavis OP wants a minimum _range_, not a minimum value...

Comment: Having read the documentation, and played with the plugin, it doesn't seem that there's any way to do this other than first parsing deriving the duration/range from the start-date and end-date, and then reporting the error to the user. Alternatively - and I haven't worked this out, hence the comment - you could possibly retrieve the start-date on the users' first click, and then define a range which would be your minimum duration. But I'm not convinced that this would work, without re-initialising the daterangepicker plugin.

Comment: You can open an issue against the author to add a new property `dateLimitMin`, which would complement the existing `dateLimit` property.

Comment: it appears OP already [asked about it](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker/issues/1282) in an issue on [the github repo](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker)

Comment: @Sam correct. I did open an issue about it on the github repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option that seems to work. Note that it doesn't block out dates or give any notification to the user, it just forces the date range to be a certain length (if user selects shorter, it changes the end date to the minimum length based on start date & min length)

https://github.com/dangrossman/daterangepicker/pull/1731/files

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer from the developer of the Date Range Picker:

> "There is not an option for that, you have to code it yourself"

https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker/issues/1282

Answer (score 0):

The following code works if the minimum date is today. You can also set your minimum date by providing it upon initialization

```
 $('input[name="view_date"]').daterangepicker({
     singleDatePicker: true,  
     minDate:new Date(), //sets minimum date to today                  
 });
```